# Printing an off_t

Tags: c, linux, printing, printf, stat

I have a problem with my C code. It prints, but way too many characters.
The code:

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<inttypes.h>
    #include<unistd.h>
    #include<sys/types.h>
    #include<sys/stat.h>
    #include<unistd.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    struct stat buff;
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
      int p, i, fd[2], n;
      char message[10], *file, *no;
      pipe(fd);
      for(i = 1; i < = argc; i++)
      {p = fork();
       if ( p == 0 )
       {
         close ( fd[0] );
         if ( access( argv[i], F_OK ) != -1 )
            {printf( "%s is an existing file \n", argv[i] );
             fflush( stdout );

             stat( (const char*)argv[i] , &buff );
             printf( "%lld", (long long)buff.st_size );
             fflush( stdout );

             //sprintf( file , "%lld" , (long long)buff.st_size);
             //write( fd[1], file /*&buff->st_size*/ ,10 );
            }
         else if ( opendir ( argv[i] ) != NULL )
                {printf("%s is an existing directory \n", argv[i]);
                 fflush(stdout);
                }
                else
                  { srand( time(NULL));
                    n = rand()%11+5;
                    sprintf( no, "%d", n);
                    printf( "%s randomly number \n", no );
                    fflush( stdout );
                    write( fd[1], no /*sizeof((char*)(((int)'0')+n))*/, 10);
                  }
         close ( fd[1] );
         exit(0);
       }
      else
        if ( p == -1 )
            {
                printf( "error" );
                exit(1);
            }
        close( fd[1] );
        read ( fd[0] , message , 10 );
        printf ( "%s \n" , message );
        fflush ( stdout );
        close ( fd[0] );
        wait(0);
    }
   return 0;
}
```

This is the entire code. I know it is not very elegant, but I didn't find a better solution for printing the `st_size`. I tried to convert it to string but that didn't worked either. It won't read through pipe anything if the argument is a file.
The output:

```
    449▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒)▒▒▒▒▒t$1▒E▒D▒E▒D$▒▒$▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒9▒rރ▒[^_]Ë$Ð▒U▒▒S▒▒▒E
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce (after adding the necessary headers, fixing `main` to return `int` and adding error checks). What compiler warnings do you get? You have the warnings turned on, don't you?

Comment: Is the code you show really the code the produces that output? That shouldn't be possible. And a small (unrelated) thing: You don't need to cast `argv[1]`, the compiler should handle it without warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this declaration:

```
char ,,,, *no;
```

And then you have this line:

```
sprintf( no, "%d", n);
```

Nowhere in the code do you allocate memory for `no`. This leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as uninitialized local variables have indeterminate values, and you are writing out into seemingly random memory.

I don't know it this is the cause of your problem, but undefined behavior can cause all kind of weird symptoms.

You either need to use e.g. `malloc` to allocate memory for the variable, or make it an array (of ten characters, as that's what you `write` later).

Comment: Thank you very much. I`ve changed `char* no` into `char no[10]` and there are no more errors.

Comment: The new problem is that it reads only the first time from pipe. So if i got more than 1 argument the parent will keep printing the result for the first argument.